# how to enable v-model binding when building a custom components from other custom components

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, v-model

I am able to build a simple textbox component from `<input />` and setup v-model binding correctly.

I'm trying to do same with a custom component: `vs-input` from **vuesax**.

Following the pattern below does not work as expected:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <vs-input type="text" v-model="value" @input="text_changed($event)" />
    <!-- <input type="text" :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)" /> -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'TestField',
  props: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {}
  },
  methods: {
    text_changed(val) {
      console.log(val)
      // this.$emit('input', val)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

In building custom components from other custom components is there anything particular we should look out for to get v-model binding working properly?

Comment: In what way is it not behaving as expected?

Comment: with the regular input box, v-model binding works. In vs-input, i'm unable to get v-model binding to work, using the same code pattern

Comment: Could you please tell me is following code working fine or not?

Comment: @PALLAMOLLASAI no. gives errors `Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "test"
`

Comment: could you please check this link once. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51954716/updating-a-prop-inside-a-child-component-so-it-updates-on-the-parent-container-t

Comment: this link also might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868963/vue-2-mutating-props-vue-warn

Comment: @PALLAMOLLASAI the first link explains it better. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Following code might help you.(Sample code try it in codepen)

[updating props inside a child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51954716/updating-a-prop-inside-a-child-component-so-it-updates-on-the-parent-container-t)

```
//html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
  <input type="text" :value="test" @change="abc">
  {{ test }}
</div>

//VUE CODE

new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data: {
     message: 'Hello Vue.js!',
      },
   props:{
     test:{
        type:String,
        default:''
     } 
   },
  methods:{
     abc:function(event){
      //console.log("abc");
      console.log(event.target.value);
      this.test=event.target.value;
    }
   }
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to interface `props` with `computed`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <vs-input type="text" v-model="cValue" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'TestField',
  props: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {}
  },
  computed: {
    cValue: {
      get: function(){
        return this.value;
      },
      set: function(val){

         // do w/e
         this.$emit('input', val)
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[Computed Setter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter)